# Parentheses around data type?

Tags: java

I am a beginning programmer and came across this in my textbook:

```
public boolean equals(DataElement otherElement)
{
    IntElement temp = (IntElement) otherElement;            
    return (num == temp.num);
}
```

`IntElement` is a subclass of `DataElement`. `num` is an int storing a value for a linked list.

What is the purpose of `(IntElement)` after `temp =?` What would be wrong with `IntElement temp = otherElement`? And, in general, what does putting a data type in parentheses like that do?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is called casting, see here:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Basically, by doing this:

```
IntElement temp = (IntElement) otherElement;
```

you are telling compiler to ignore the fact you declared `otherElement` as `DataElement` and trust you it is going to be an `IntElement` and not `DataElement` or some other subclass of `DataElement`.

You cannot do just `IntElement temp = otherElement;` as this way you would make `otherElement`, which was defined as `DataElement` become some other element, in this case `IntElement`. This will be a big blow to type-safety, which is the reason types are defined at the first place.

This could technically be done using type inference:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_inference

however Java does not support that and you have to be explicit.

If it's possible to get other elements, you may want to use `instanceof` to check the type runtime before casting:

- Operators/TheinstanceofKeyword.htm">http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0060_Operators/TheinstanceofKeyword.htm

At some point after you go through this, you might want to take a look at generics, too:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java

Answer (score 3):

The purpose of `(IntElement)` after `temp` is performing a type conversion, more technically, a *cast*, where you're saying that `otherElement`, which is a parameter of type `DataElement`, should be taken as an object of the more concrete type `IntElement`.

Answer (score 1):

**(IntElement)** casts otherElement which is of type **DataElement** to type **IntElement**

Check out this link about [Java Types and Type Conversion (Casting)](http://xahlee.info/java-a-day/casting.html) for a more thorough description.

Answer (score 1):

jmein is correct, it tells the compiler/interpreter to turn the one variable type into another. In reality it is just telling the processor to treat it as another type. In C this is a blessing and a curse, in java, what looks like you are writing, you MUST cast the variable to treat it differently.

Answer (score 0):

It is a type cast[See the example here](http://www.javabeginner.com/learn-java/java-object-typecasting)